# Where is javadoc for Eclipse SWT?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, javadoc

I get the message:

> Note: This element has no attached Javadoc and the Javadoc could not
> be found in the attached source.

When trying to see docs for `setUrl`

```
browser.setUrl("http://palplays.com/");
```

I have in the build path of Eclipse project tried to search for jar and also tried adding

```
https://www.eclipse.org/swt/javadoc.php
```

The jar is called like:

org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.114.100.v20200604-0951.jar (javadocversion)

I tried the Java installation src:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\src
```

I look on Eclipse SWT download page and follow tutorial for SWT but no information it's like a black hold?

I suspect my installation is broken maybe!

Comment: Is this an Eclipse plug-in you are doing or a standalone SWT program? `org.eclipse.swt.xxxx` jars are for plug-ins. For a standalone SWT download the appropriate SWT zip from the Eclipse Project page [here](https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.16-202006040540/) - SWT Binary and Source section. The zip has the jar and source code which Eclipse will use for the Javadoc.

Comment: I go to [Eclipse website](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/) and download this  eclipse-jee-2020-06-R-win32-x86_64.zip , that's the  Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers 400MB full suit

Comment: That is not relevant, if you are doing a standalone SWT app you should use the SWT jars that I pointed to. The org.eclipse.swt jars are used by Eclipse plug-ins and the source/javadoc is packaged differently. If you want to do plugin development there is a package that contains all the Eclipse source/javadoc including SWT.

Comment: I will look into that Thanks. I dont do plugin development I just learn some Java tutorials!

Comment: This is how it [look](https://snipboard.io/JPvH5u.jpg) just Java

Comment: I tried what you say and download [SWT Binary and Source](https://snipboard.io/7btwY4.jpg).
I then use it

Comment: Then I [tried](https://snipboard.io/Qp8m3f.jpg) various ways to make Eclipse accept the jar, folder or zip as source docs but no luck

Comment: Here you see [folder how I try to unzip, use zip, use jar](https://snipboard.io/6kRPbG.jpg) but not javadoc

Comment: Eclipse should find the Javadoc in the source without a javadoc setting.

Comment: @greg-449 how can I get javadoc for basic SWT widgets so I can learn and understand. Right now I [use this online docs](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/javadoc.php) but it's super counterproductive

Comment: It is included in the Eclipse Help if you use an Eclipse package that includes the plug-in development code. In the 'API Reference' section of the 'Platform Plug-in Developer Guide'

Comment: I know the javadocs are in the help and on the Eclipse website but I want it in the code editor but  when I hover over it say "Note: This element has no attached Javadoc and the Javadoc could not be found in the attached source".  I

Comment: All I can say is that it works for me. The source in the src.zip does contain the Javadoc. Try pressing F3 on one of the SWT classes to open the source

Comment: That sound good. Look here I even download the javdoc jar and add it but no javadocs works. What version of Eclipse should I use? I looking into Jbuilder now also the Netbeans
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/platform/org.eclipse.swt/

Comment: It's like a cruel  joke LOL [look here](https://snipboard.io/IT5pmF.jpg) I download the javadoc then open it and it say  - Corresponding javadoc can be found in artifact org.eclipse.platform:org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv. I then go [there](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.platform/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/4.16.0) and download it Eclipse does not see it as javadoc

Comment: I managed to add javadoc to [logback](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch/qos/logback/logback-access/1.2.3/) so Eclipse work ok I think but for Java itself no